# Google Sheets - compare 2 (4) columns

Tags: google-sheets, outlook, vlookup

This has to be simpler than it seems. I have 100 rows. Col A is registration status, let's say "Registered". Col B is the person's email address. Cols C and D are pulled from Outlook's calendar tracking, which gives their email in Col C, and their reply, let's say "Accepted", in col D.

The issue is, many who have accepted the invite haven't registered for the event. Or they've registered but haven't accepted. etc etc.

EDIT: Forgot to add, Cols A and C *ARE NOT ORDERED THE SAME*. Col A has the 100 people actually invited, Col C has people that aren't. Simply put, way too much effort to fix that.

I need a way to find all the discrepancies. Thanks so much!!

EDIT2 - sample spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BU4Z6YQlvm1VqIbfq131muh6ElJqHR5wGDMwson-g8s/edit?usp=sharing

I want to see that - for example - Deb accepted the calendar invite (col D) despite not registering for the event (col A). That's a discrepancy I'd need to investigate.

Comment: i'm sure it will be simple like you say, but it's hard to help without you sharing a sample sheet of some sort.

Just a simple mock up shared *with editing* permissions will allow me or others here to help really quickly.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Good point. Sample spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BU4Z6YQlvm1VqIbfq131muh6ElJqHR5wGDMwson-g8s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think there is not clear how you want your expected output to be. Do you want to extract the discrepancy in another range, color the rows, delete them? I believe that's what @player0 refer with "desired output" not just the data that you already told us about. Also it would be nice if you could list all the things that would be a discrepancy for you.